# Kubernetes add pod IPs into environment variable

Tags: service, kubernetes, environment-variables, yaml

I have a Kafka deployment and service deployed via Kubernetes. Each its pods have its internal IP and with a **command** like this

```
kubectl describe services broker --namespace=kafka | grep Endpoints | awk '{print $2}'
```

I can get them all: `10.244.1.11:9092,10.244.2.15:9092,10.244.2.16:9092`

I have another service deployed with Kubernetes, after my Kafka, that needs the result of that command as an environment variable KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS.

How can I get **the result of that command into an environment variable** in my service kubernetes YML file?

Answer (score 1):

You should develop a client program in python or go and using the service account that gets mounted in each container, hit the api server endpoint and retrieve Kafka endpoints. Parse the Json file output abd grab the actual broker ip addresses

Comment: I'm looking for something more out-of-the-box, to be run in some YML file of Kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes allow you to use environmental variables. [Here is the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config).

You can also use HELM to use templates which also allow the use of the environmental variables.

In your case, you can get the result in an env variable like as below:

SOME_ENV_VARIABLE=[$( command... )](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147420/what-is-in-a-command)

Comment: This does not solve my question. Following the link that posted about how to set environment variables, what ideally I would need would be get result of the command in the value, like -> value: $(kubectl describe services broker --namespace=kafka | grep Endpoints | awk '{print $2}') But I think this is not possible